# C# -- Knowing a base type of a Generic Type

Tags: c#, func

How can I find out the base type of a generic type?

For example

```
 Func<A, B>
```

I'd like to be able to say this is a Func<> .. but apparently, Func<,> is different from Func<> -- Is there a way to somehow catch them both, or Func<,,,> etc?

Comment: What do you mean by base type? You want to get `Func<>`?

Comment: @user986697 - have updated my answer with an actual solution to what you're asking, and some more explanation that might help you in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `GetGenericTypeDefinition`:

```
var t = typeof(Func<int, string>);
var tGeneric = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
Assert.AreEqual(typeof(Func<,>), tGeneric);
```

If you then want to know if a type is one of the many `Func<>` variants, then your best best is simply to do something like this.  Checking type names, as suggested elsewhere is absolutely NOT the way to check type identity:

```
static Type[] funcGenerics = new[]{
  typeof(Func<>), typeof(Func<,>), typeof(Func<,,>), typeof(Func<,,,>),
  /* and so on... */
}
//there are other ways to do the above - but this is the most explicit.


static bool IsFuncType(Type t)
{
  if(t.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
    return funcGenerics.Any(tt => tt == t);
  else if(t.IsGenericType) 
    return IsFuncType(t.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
  return false;
}
```

Your terminology is incorrect - which I suspect why you got a downvote on your question.  A base type is one that a type inherits from (not an interface, which is different, although conceptually very similar).

A generic type definition is best thought of as being ***like*** a template (the strong qualification there because the term 'template' is used in C++ and, while visually similar they are very different in implementation).

More accurately, `Func<,>` is a generic type definition whereas `Func<int, string>` is a *closed* generic (the 'generic type').

You can also have an open generic, which is where the type arguments are generic parameters - e.g, given:

```
class MyType<T> : List<T> { }
```

Then `List<T>` is an open generic with the generic type definition `List<>`, because `T` is a generic parameter which will not be closed till `MyType<T>` is referenced with a concrete type argument, such as `int` or `string`.

Finally, just because a bunch of generic types share the same common name, e.g. `Func<>`, `Func<,>`, and `Func<,,>` it does not mean they are in any way related.  At the type level, there is no explicit connection, which is why you have to check for all these type identities, and why there is no common 'base' as you put it.  If they all had a common interface or base class, however, then you could - by checking for compatibility with that interface or base type.

Given a generic type definition, you can construct generic types using `MakeGenericType`, as has been mentioned by Jeffrey Zhang.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't, There is not a base type of a Gerneric Type. If you want to get a specific generic type by type parameters, You can use `MakeGenericType`. For example:

```
//get Func<int, string> type
typeof(Func<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), typeof(string));
```

If you want to get a Generic Type from specified generic type, You can use `GetGenericTypeDefinition`. For example:

```
//get Func<,> type
typeof(Func<int, string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition();
```

Comment: Isn't better GetGenericDefinition? `typeof(Func<A, B>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Func<>))`;

Comment: @pwas That's cool, I don't know this method before. Can i update answer base you comment?

Answer (score 0):

It is Because `Func< A, B >` does not inherit from `Func<>` It is a generic based on `Func<,>`.

However, you will notice that

```
typeof(Func<int, int>).FullName // equals "System.Func`2...
typeof(Func<int, int, int>).FullName // equals "System.Func`3...
```

It is a bit ugly but you could use something like

```
YourType.FullName.StartsWith("System.Func")
```

Hope it helps

Edit: 
**Why not use `YourType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()`?**

Because `typeof(Func<int, int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()` returns `Func<,>`

and `typeof(Func<int, int, int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition()` return `Func<,,>`.

`Func<,>` and `Func<,,>` are not the same Type.

Comment: I don't think it's good idea to rely on FullName. I'ts better to use `GetGenerictTypeDefinition`.

Comment: sorry - this is just not the right way to do what the OP asks, albeit using obscure language

Comment: @pwas but `GetGenericTypeDefinition` doesn't solve the problem. The problem is how to know if it is a Func of arbitrary arity. GetGenericTypeDefinition just returns an open generic type of the same arity.

Comment: @pwas Yes but the orginial question is about identifying Func<A,B> func<A,B,C> etc. as "Func". The generic type will not provide that kind of information because Func<A,B> has Func<,> as generic type and Func<A,B,C> has Func<,,> as generic type, they are different and I understood that user986697 wants to identify both as 'Func'. Unfortunately, there is not relation between Func<,> and Func<,,> for instance... except their name.

Comment: @Dubbs777 - nope. `typeof(<FuncA,B>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(<FuncA,B, C>).GetGenericTypeDefinition())` and it equals `typeof(Func<>)` - so there is relation except name.

Comment: @pwas, Maybe I did not understand something but in my code, `typeof(Func<int, int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Func<int, int, int>).GetGenericTypeDefinition())` answers false...

Comment: @Dubbs777 ahh yes, you are right. My mistake, it returns `GetGenericDefinition` returns class with generic arguments non-specified, but still remembers the count of that arguments. Then, name is the only way.

Comment: @pwas, no problem. My answer was not very clear to begin with anyway... I will try to edit it (with proper formatting this time)